# Adding and Removing Items when having new process C#

Tags: c#

Hi everyboy I have some problem with Multi Thread and ListView Update:
I want to list running process by name in a Listview, and removing when this process close. But my code just adding a new process and dont remove when the process close. I am a beginner user in C#. Thank you. 
*** I dont want to use listview.Clear() cause Im going to make a bot with multi client

Here's my code:

```
bool status = true;
int[] PID = new int[10];
Memory Mem = new Memory();

private void startChecking()
    {

        while (status)
        {
            try
            {
                int count = 0;
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
                if (processes.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (listAccount.Items.Count < processes.Length)
                    {
                        foreach (Process process in processes)
                        {
                            if (listAccount.Items.Count < processes.Length && PID[count] != process.Id)
                            {
                                Mem.SetTitle(process.MainWindowHandle, "Cyber Auto - " + count.ToString());
                                AddItemNew(process.MainWindowTitle);
                                PID[count] = process.Id;
                            }
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (listAccount.Items.Count < processes.Length)
                    {

                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Somethine went wrong : " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my AddItemNew / RemoveItem methods:

```
private delegate void dlgAddItemNew(string i);
    private void AddItemNew(string i)
    {
        if (this.listAccount.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new dlgAddItemNew(AddItemNew), i);
        }
        else
        {
            ListViewItem accountAdd = new ListViewItem(i);
            accountAdd.SubItems.Add("0");
            accountAdd.SubItems.Add("0");
            accountAdd.SubItems.Add("0");
            accountAdd.SubItems.Add("0");
            this.listAccount.Items.Add(accountAdd);
        }
    }
    private delegate void dlgRemoveItem(int i);
    private void RemoveItem(int i)
    {
        if (this.listAccount.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new dlgRemoveItem(RemoveItem), i);
        }
        else
        {
            this.listAccount.Items[i].Remove();
        }
    }
```

P/S : Sorry If my Enlish is not good....

Comment: May we see the `AddItemNew` /  `RemoveItem` methods ? Apart from the fact that you're only counting the process and not checking their PIDs nothing seems wrong here.

Comment: Do you want this to happen as the process close, or are you ok to wait for 2000 ms ? If you are willing to wait, then just re-list all the processes everytime.

Comment: Can you give me more e.g? Im a newbie so I dont understand much your meaning. @Captain0. #Sidewinder94 I add my methods in under comment :D

Comment: This seems overly complicated just to list processes.... Captain0 is right here, if you're waiting 2 seconds before refreshing, you'd better re-list all the processes every two seconds.

Comment: [Video](https://youtu.be/7FV8HLidAAI) this's my clip about my problem. And when I close some process the listview will remove item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check at periodic interval, then you can clear the ListView before populating it again. (This is what Captain0 meant in his comments above)

I have modified your code a bit and I can see it working when I open/close  instance of notepad, it update the count, No need for separate add/remove items (unless you had to something different in opening & closing of notepad process)

```
private void startChecking()
 {
    while (status)
    {
       try
       {
          Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
          UpdateListView(processes.Count());
          Thread.Sleep(2000);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show("Somethine went wrong : " + ex.ToString());
          status = false;
        }
     }
}

private void UpdateListView(int processCount)
{
    if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
       Action action = () => UpdateListView(processCount);
       Invoke(action);
    }
    else
    {
      listView1.Items.Clear(); // Clearing the List view before adding them again
      for (int i = 0; i < processCount; i++)
      {
         ListViewItem accountAdd = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());
         listView1.Items.Add(accountAdd);
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nope, I wanna add one line for one process cause I will use checkbox in listview item @Pankaj

Comment: @OnlyU, I have modified my code , It will now display as many checkboxes  in the listview as there are notepad instances and will keep on updating, Make sure you do listView1.CheckBoxes = true;

Comment: [link](https://youtu.be/7FV8HLidAAI) this's my mean! And when I close some process the listview will update